# Read html file using Pandas, Python

Tags: python, html, pandas

I like to read the .html file in pandas, Please see the source htm below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Output File</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<span style='color:black'>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<span style='color:black'>| Study Case: Case A_Lines                                                                         | Annex:                  / 1  |</span>
<span style='color:black'>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<span style='color:black'>| System Summary                                                                                                                  |</span>
<span style='color:black'>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<span style='color:black'>| System Average Interruption Frequency Index          :  SAIFI  =    0.373016 1/Ca                                               |</span>
<span style='color:black'>| Customer Average Interruption Frequency Index        :  CAIFI  =    0.373016 1/Ca                                               |</span>
<span style='color:black'>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<span style='color:black'></span>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

The most relevant information that I am trying to read is the table of indexes and values like,

```
SAIFI 0.373016 1/Ca
```

I have tried reading it directly with number of options but failed.

```
df = pd.read_html(path, match='=')
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with `pandas` but it returned an error. Can you try with `BeautifulSoap`?:

```
In [20]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [21]: f = BeautifulSoup(open("file.html"))
In [22]: f.findAll("span")[5].text.split()[-3]
Out[22]: u'0.373016'
```

Of course you can improve the way I used for identifying the value.

Thanks

Comment: you are welcome, if you are happy please accept the answer :)